# Is there any way to pass a prop to slot in svelte?

Tags: svelte

I have a parent component with a slot,
and a child component put into the parent as a slot.

I want to pass a prop "gutter" to the child component through parent component.

Is there any way to do this without context and store?

All I want is like this.
The parent component: ParentComp.svelte

```
<script>
    export let gutter = 0;
</script>

<div>
    <slot gutter={gutter}></slot>
</div>
```

The child component: ChildComp.svelte

```
<script>
    export let gutter = 0;
</script>

<div>
    gutter is: {gutter}
    <slot></slot>
</div>
```

App.svelte

```
<script>
    import ParentComp from './ParentComp.svelte'
    import ChildComp from './ChildComp.svelte'
</script>

<ParentComp gutter=10>
    <ChildComp>
        <ParentComp gutter=8>
            <ChildComp></ChildComp>
        </ParentComp>
    </ChildComp>
</ParentComp>
```

Actually, what I am doing is to make layout components with a row component(Parent) and a column component(child).
I want to control the gutter prop of row and column in with single variable.

I can't use the context or store to do this, because sometimes there is a row in the column.

Comment: I dont think that this is possible. You can try looking at this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61960147/how-to-pass-data-from-child-to-parent-with-2-svelte-components-in-html-parent-ch

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried to use Svelte context, and this can solve my problem!!!!
I should not exclude the context in my question, Sorry, it's my mistake.

I made a sample here, and the context works well.
[Sample](https://svelte.dev/repl/db7ab444eb77408184cdaf2eb8770ffc?version=3.31.0)

Comment: the problem of context is it is not reactive like props do

Comment: @AbbyChauYuHoi  context could be reactive, just use store inside the context variable.
Reference: https://www.arzidava.com/blog/svelte-contextapi-stores/

Comment: countext can be reactive if what you save is a store ;)